# Could not find CMake package configuration file for "PugiXml"

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, ubuntu-18.04, pugixml

I am trying to build a tool from a git repo and after executing "cmake .." I get the following error:

```
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "PugiXml" with any
of the following names:

PugiXmlConfig.cmake
pugixml-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "PugiXml" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"PugiXml_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
"PugiXml" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
been installed.
```

I also got this error for Eigen3 and Qt5. I solved them by executing
`sudo apt install libeigen3-dev` / `sudo apt install libqt5svg5-dev`. But apparently this is not working for pugiXml with `sudo apt install libpugixml-dev`.

Anyone got a solution for this?

Comment: Start with the [tour] and read [ask], please. Your question is not about programming but about installing some software. Generally, you will find better help looking for a how-to on that topic.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt The question is fine and about 70% of all CMake question are just like that.

Comment: They basically say that they fixed a similar error by installing the missing component. How is this case different? Only that it's not packaged for their OS perhaps? We don't know what "apperently this is not working" means. These are infos that should be included in a good question.

Comment: According to the Ubuntu repositories, the file `pugixml-config.cmake` is provided by `libpugixml-dev` package, but on Ubuntu 18.04 it is located at `/usr/share/libpugixml-dev/cmake/pugixml-config.cmake`: https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/libpugixml-dev/filelist. I guess CMake simply doesn't search that location by default. For newer Ubuntu versions the file has more "standard" location `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/pugixml/pugixml-config.cmake`: https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/libpugixml-dev/filelist.

Comment: You´re right @Tsyvarev. Can you also tell me how I can set the "PugiXml_DIR" to this directory?

Comment: Pass additional parameter to `cmake`: `-DPugiXml_DIR=/usr/share/libpugixml-dev/cmake`.

Answer (score 0):

I use the centos os ,  When I install soft from the vcpkg ， it allways pop the error , here is how i fix it .

1. sodo yum install 'softname' like 'pugixml' or 'libxml2' .then it will tell us what lib we should install
2. install the specify lib, like 'sudo yum install sudo yum install  pugixml-devel' or 'sudo yum install libxml-devel'